# Calculus by Apostol Exercise 2.8 number 30

Tags: calculus, analysis

[image: Problem]

I have no idea on how to start proving this, but I know the theorem is stating that the integral of a translated periodic function is the same with the integral of the periodic function without translation, is this concept correct? What I am thinking is to use the translation property of integrals to manipulate the equation but so far no success. Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $f$ is periodic, $\forall n: \int_{[0,p]}fdx=\int_{[np,(n+1)p[}fdx$. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then you can find a unique interval $[Np,(N+1)p[$ which includes $a$. Then you may divide $[a,a+p]$ into two segments, namely $[a,(N+1)p[\cup[(N+1)p,a+p]$.

---

**Edit:** Let us fill in the details:

$\int_{[a,a+p]}fdx= \int_{[a,(N+1)p]\cup[(N+1)p,a+p]}fdx= \int_{[a,(N+1)p]}fdx+\int_{[(N+1)p,a+p]}fdx= \int_{[a,(N+1)p]}fdx+ \int_{[Np,a]+p}fdx =\int_{[a,(N+1)p]}fdx+\int_{[Np,a]}f(x+p)dx= \int_{[a,(N+1)p]}fdx+\int_{[Np,a]}fdx= \int_{[Np,(N+1)p]}fdx= \int_{[0,p]}fdx.$

Comment: Where did the n come from? Why do you have to expand the boundaries?

Comment: $n$'s comes into play when you partition the real line into disjoint intervals of length $p$. What do you mean by "expanding the boundaries"?

Comment: I know that we can divide p into n partitions but I don't understand what you did in the limits of integration [np, (n+1)p].

Comment: Are you asking why I take half open half closed intervals? Well, it doesn't really matter whether you take the endpoints of the interval when integrating, so you may consider it a notational preference. In other words, $f\in R([a,b])\implies\int_{[a,b]}fdx=\int_{[a,b[}fdx=\int_{]a,b]}fdx=\int_{]a,b[}fdx$.

Comment: Basically I still don't get it with your hint.

Comment: Let f be a periodic function with period p. ∫f(x)dx 0 to p is equal to ∫f(x+p)dx 0 to p since f is periodic. ∫f(x+p)dx 0 to p is equal to ∫f(x)dx np to np+p from the translation property. We can find a unique interval say, Np to Np+p where it contains a. Let Np=a, then ∫f(x)dx Np to Np+p is equal to ∫f(x)dx a to a+p. Is this rigorous enough?

Comment: Almost, only you don't know $Np=a$. Let me write it down in my answer.

Comment: How would you write it?